Share login in Playwright for all the tests
I'm creating some Playwright tests, for which the first step is to login in the application.
If I do that in every test, things work as expected, but the login is executed in every test.
I have something like
async function login(page) {
    await page.goto('<login page>', {
        waitUntil: 'commit',
        timeout: 500000,
    });
}

test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
    await login(page);
});

test()......

How can I login once, save the context of that moment when the login worked, and use it at the beginning of each test, so I don't need to login on every test?

Did you read https://playwright.dev/docs/auth? This page clearly explains a variety of different auth strategies.
